# Python: Shopping list: Items not storing

Tags: python, list

Intro: I am trying to put a shopping list code together. However, every time that I input an item, instead of storing the item in the list, I get a error saying that that item is not defined.

```
shopping_list = []


def show_help():
    print("What should we pick up at the store?")

    print("""
  Enter 'DONE' to stop adding items.
  Enter 'HELP' for this help.
  Enter 'SHOW' to see your current list.
  """)


def add_to_list():
shopping_list.append(new_item)
print("Here is the item that it's been added {}. There are now {} items".format(new_item, len(shopping_list)))


def show_list():
    index =  1
    for index, item in shopping_list:
        print("Here is the current  shopping list: {}. {}".format(index,item))
    index = index + 1
show_help()

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")

     if new_item == 'DONE':
        break
     elif new_item == 'HELP':
        show_help()
        continue
     elif new_item == 'SHOW':
        show_list()
        continue

     add_to_list()

show_list()
```

Question: Why is not storing the string into the list?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hi, please format your code by providing proper indentation in order to produce a minimal, verifiable, and complete example.

Answer (score 0):

That is true because you are not passing any item to `add_to_list()` method.

The code should be like:

```
shopping_list = []


def show_help():
    print("What should we pick up at the store?")

    print("""
  Enter 'DONE' to stop adding items.
  Enter 'HELP' for this help.
  Enter 'SHOW' to see your current list.
  """)


def add_to_list(new_item):
    shopping_list.append(new_item)
    print("Here is the item that it's been added {}. There are now {} items".format(new_item, len(shopping_list)))


def show_list():
    index =  1
    for index, item in shopping_list:
        print("Here is the current  shopping list: {}. {}".format(index,item))
    index = index + 1
show_help()

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")

     if new_item == 'DONE':
        break
     elif new_item == 'HELP':
        show_help()
        continue
     elif new_item == 'SHOW':
        show_list()
        continue

     add_to_list(new_item)

show_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` ***interprets*** the input, i.e. If the user e.g. puts in an integer value, the input function returns this integer value. If the user on the other hand inputs a list, the function will return a list.

If you don't wrap your input into quotes, Python takes your name as a variable. So, the error message makes sense!

To avoid this error you have to cast the variable *input* into a string. eg: "ABC"

---

Alternatively, you can use `raw_input()`. `raw_input` ***does not interpret*** the input. It always returns the input of the user without changes, i.e. raw. This raw input can be changed into the data type needed for the algorithm.

[Further Reading](https://www.python-course.eu/input.php)

Comment: You should mention this is only the case in Python 2. In Python 3 `raw_input()` does not exist, as `raw_input()` was changed to be `input()`, and the `input()` function from Python 2 does not exist in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

you also had the function `show_list` wrong. This was test on Python 3.7

```
shopping_list = []

def show_help():
    print("What should we pick up at the store?")

    print("""
  Enter 'DONE' to stop adding items.
  Enter 'HELP' for this help.
  Enter 'SHOW' to see your current list.
  """)


def add_to_list():
    shopping_list.append(new_item)
    print("Here is the item that it's been added {}. There are now {} items".format(new_item, len(shopping_list)))


def show_list():
    for index, item in enumerate(shopping_list):
        print("Here is the current  shopping list: {}. {}".format(index, item))
    show_help()

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")

    if new_item == 'DONE':
        break
    elif new_item == 'HELP':
        show_help()
        continue
    elif new_item == 'SHOW':
        show_list()
        continue

    add_to_list()

show_list()
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your error given, I think you might be using Python 2.7 and the error is because you used `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. When using Python 3 `input()` should be used.

So change `new_item = input("> ")` to be `new_item = raw_input("> ")` and that should stop your error.

---

However there is also an error in your code where you print out the final list in the `show_list` function as well. A for loop only goes through each item in teh list unless you call `enumerate` which will return the index and the item as it loops through.

This is probably what you are looking for in that function:

```
def show_list():
    for index, item in enumerate(shopping_list):
        print("Here is the current shopping list: {}. {}".format(index,item))
```